# Arduino, Pass return of jsonBuffer.parseObject to a function

Tags: c++, json, arduino

I am following this example: https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson/wiki/Decoding-JSON

```
JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(json);
```

I want to pass root into a function, and use it within the function.

```
//Call it
test(root);

// Define here
void test(JsonObject* root) {
   int flag = (*root)["success"]; // Not sure how to do it
}
```

Compiled error:

```
error: could not convert '& root' from 'ArduinoJson::JsonObject*' to 'ArduinoJson::JsonObject'
```

Sorry, I have poor understanding of pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your function is taking a pointer you'll need to get the address of `root` before you pass it. This is done using the `&` (addressof) operator.

```
JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(json);

test( &root );  //Get address of root, then pass that pointer to function.

void test(JsonObject* root) {  //Pass pointer by value
   int flag = (*root)["success"]; 
}
```

However, you should use a reference, then your code will be a bit simpler, and also look a lot cleaner (no addressof and no dereferenced pointers).

```
JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(json);

test( root );

void test(JsonObject &root) {  // Pass by reference.
   int flag = root["success"];
}
```